# HtmlAgilityPack Get page control names and Type of properties

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get all controls names and type of control if it is a textbox or checkbox etc using HtmlAgilityPack. I always see the value as null. what may be the issue?

```
            HtmlDocument htmlCode = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlCode.LoadHtml("http://www.google.com");
            //var htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
            HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");

            HtmlNode myForm = htmlCode.GetElementbyId("form");

            foreach (HtmlNode node in myForm.Elements("input"))
            {
                HtmlAttribute valueAttribute = node.Attributes["value"];

                if (valueAttribute != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(valueAttribute.Value);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you cannot load a page from a url using `HtmlDocument` (not directly).  Running that would have given you an error anyway.  You have to download the contents separately and load it or just use `HtmlWeb` to load it.

The workaround for fixing the way `form` elements are handled must be set *before* you parse the document. Otherwise, the changes will have no effect.

Your sample code assumes that there's a `form` element named `form` and inputs may be its immediate children.  Inputs in an enclosing form doesn't necessarily have to be a child of the form, it may be a descendant anywhere within the tree.

If you're just looking for all form fields, regardless of the form, just look for all descendants of the appropriate type.

```
string GetControlType(HtmlNode n)
{
    switch (n.Name)
    {
    case "button": return n.GetAttributeValue("type", "(submit)");
    case "input":  return n.GetAttributeValue("type", "(text)");
    default:       return null;
    }
}
string GetControlValue(HtmlNode n)
{
    switch (n.Name)
    {
    case "button":
    case "input":
        return n.GetAttributeValue("value", null);
    case "select":
        if (n.Descendants("option").SkipWhile(x => x.Attributes["selected"] == null).FirstOrDefault() is HtmlNode o) return o.GetAttributeValue("value", null);
        return n.Descendants("option").FirstOrDefault()?.GetAttributeValue("value", null);
    case "textarea":
        return n.InnerText;
    default: return null;
    }
}

HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");    
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.google.com");
var fields = new[] { "button", "input", "select", "textarea" };
var query =
    from n in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
    where fields.Contains(n.Name)
    let controlType = GetControlType(n)
    let controlValue = GetControlValue(n)
    select new
    {
        ControlName = n.Name,
        ControlType = controlType,
        Name = n.GetAttributeValue("name", null),
        Value = controlValue,
        OuterHtml = n.OuterHtml,
    };
```